Redefining Redshift Without Needing Dark Energy or Cosmic Expansion
I feel like we have made so many theories to try to explain a single phenomenon, redshift. If we stick to Newtonian physics we don't need dark energy or expansion of the universe beyond the speed of light.
Here's how Newtonian physics can explain our observable universe without fringe physics:

Space is infinite, but the observable universe is finite
The observable universe is finite and has boundaries defined by the limits of what we can see based on the speed of light and the time it has taken for light from distant objects to reach us. Light from distant stars and galaxies takes millions to billions of years to reach us, so we only see a "snapshot" of the universe at a certain point in time.

We can think of the observable universe as a finite, spherical region, with us at the center of that sphere. The edge of this sphere is the furthest distance light can travel since the beginning of the universe. There is likely more to the universe (e.g. galaxies) beyond our observational range that may not be immediately viewable.
This provides a model where we live in a region of the universe that is expanding, but space itself is not “stretching”.

The Cosmic "Shotgun Blast" Model
Imagine a colossal explosion, akin to a shotgun blast, that scattered matter outward. The galaxies we see are simply moving away from each other as a result of this initial momentum. All of the universe's galaxies are still moving relative to one another as a result of this initial distribution of matter and energy.

Galaxies that are farther from us are moving away faster due to their initial velocity. This causes the redshift we observe, which is explained by a straightforward Doppler effect. The greater the distance, the faster the galaxies are receding from us, producing an increasing redshift.
This is perfectly in line with Newton's Laws of Motion and doesn't require any space expansion or bending.

Gravitational Forces and Large-Scale Structure
On larger scales, the gravitational force of galaxies would cause some to cluster together, forming large galactic clusters, superclusters, and voids. These clusters and the large-scale structure of the universe can be understood through Newtonian gravity. The force of gravity between galaxies causes them to form patterns or structures that we observe today.

Over time, the gravitational attraction between galaxies would cause a slowing down of their relative motion as they interact with one another. Eventually, distant galaxies will slow and become more gravitationally bound as they approach one another.
Because of this gravitational attraction, galaxies that are closer to the center of the observable universe will eventually slow down more rapidly than galaxies further away from the center of the “blast” as there are greater gravitational forces interacting with them.

Cosmic Radiation
The Cosmic Microwave Background (CMB) could still exist as a relic from this initial explosion. This radiation would have been emitted in the form of electromagnetic waves, and it would still be observable today, albeit redshifted due to the ongoing motion of galaxies and not because space itself is expanding.

“Middle” of the Universe
If we are in the “middle” of the observable universe, or even somewhere interior of the “blast”, then it makes sense that we see galaxies moving away from us in all directions. The uniformity of the CMB radiation could simply be the result of us being in the center of the universe’s observable region, not necessarily because the universe is homogenous or infinite.


If the emptiness of space were infinite, and the matter and energy that fills the universe is finite from the initial “blast”, that blast would theoretically continue traveling in a single direction while spreading out, with the outermost regions retaining a higher velocity while the inner regions slow and pull against one another.
==========================================================================
Now, what if particles exhibit different behaviors when their mass falls below a certain threshold?
If this were so then mass would no longer be a strictly linear property, but one that undergoes phase transitions when it reaches extremely low values. This would mean that particles with extremely low mass might experience a shift in behavior once a certain mass threshold is crossed.
For example, particles with extremely low mass could become less constrained by spacetime, potentially leading to effects that mimic faster-than-light, near-light, or speed-of-light behavior without violating special relativity.
Additionally, quantum mechanical properties could cause the particles to behave more like waveforms, allowing for effects like diffraction, refraction, or other wave-like properties to dominate, which could potentially provide an alternative explanation for redshift and other cosmological observations
Traditionally, photons are considered massless; however, if they do have an infinitesimally small but non-zero mass, they might experience different propagation dynamics over cosmic distances explaining why photons from distant galaxies appear to redshift as the photons lose energy differently when their effective mass is below a critical threshold, or due to interactions with the "medium" of spacetime itself.
Furthermore, if light particles are affected by a unique form of inertia at extremely low effective mass, they might experience gradual energy decay over vast distances due to some form of quantum friction or resistance from spacetime fluctuations causing the apparent elongation of wavelengths as they travel, independent of the galactic motion or universal expansion.
Einstein's conversion of mass into energy suggests the converse affect of converting energy back into mass. The theory is also further supported by the concept of Pair Production, where a high-energy photon (e.g. gamma-rays) is converted into a particle-antiparticle pair (e.g. an electron and a positron). This by itself should prove that photons are not truly massless.
If this hypothesis were to be taken seriously, how might it be tested?
Has CERN tested using colliders to attempt to generate particles with extremely low effective mass and observe if their interactions deviate from predictions made by the Standard Model?
Have discrepancies been identified in redshift patterns that cannot be fully accounted for by cosmological expansion, particularly in areas where gravitational lensing or cosmic voids might alter particle behavior?
If I viewed the universe in this way, what is being left out that I'm not accounting for? What additional observations have we made that might negate this much simpler view of our universe and how it expands?

Newtonian physics can explain... based on the speed of light Your assumptions are incompatible.

There are a few issues here.
You’re not accounting for what the Big Bang actually was, primarily. It’s very frequently misunderstood by non-cosmologists as an explosion of matter outward into empty space. That is not what it was. Basically all your other misconceptions stem from right there.


The Cosmic "Shotgun Blast" Model Imagine a colossal explosion, akin to a shotgun blast, that scattered matter outward. The galaxies we see are simply moving away from each other as a result of this initial momentum. All of the universe's galaxies are still moving relative to one another as a result of this initial distribution of matter and energy.

This doesn’t match observations. More-distant galaxies are observed to have more velocity by a constant of proportionality of just about $H$; sure, there’s no reason we couldn’t be mistaking an explosion for Universal expansion, but if this were an explosion, our galaxy - in fact, our sun; in fact, our very planet - would be at the exact center of the whole Universe. Is that technically impossible? No. Is it so improbable that in a hundred billion Universes it still would be unlikely to ever happen? Yes.
Cosmological expansion also helps explain the redshift patterns in distant galaxies. The whole reason the Big Bang is considered is because in a monotonically-expanding Universe, the FLRW metric dictates the existence of a past-directed singularity at infinity, a point at which all distances in the Universe were zero. The transition from all-distances-zero to all-distances-nonzero is what the Big Bang was. It is commonly misrepresented in pop-sci as an actual explosion, but there was no explosion - it was simply a transition from one type of geometry to another.

Over time, the gravitational attraction between galaxies would cause a slowing down of their relative motion as they interact gravitationally. Eventually, distant galaxies will slow and become more gravitationally bound as they approach one another.

What we have observed is that the expansion - the velocity between galaxies per unit distance apart - is accelerating. At super-large scales, expansion dominates gravity. It sucks, ‘cause that means a Big Rip is a possibility, but it likely won’t happen before the Heat Death anyway.

Cosmic Radiation The Cosmic Microwave Background (CMB) could still exist as a relic from this initial explosion. This radiation would have been emitted in the form of electromagnetic waves, and it would still be observable today, albeit redshifted due to the ongoing motion of galaxies and not because space itself is expanding.

Again, there was no explosion. The matter mostly stayed put (and went through interesting phase transitions and symmetry breaking and what have ye), but immediately after the Big Bang, space was already infinite and matter homogenously covered it all. There was no single point with matter radiating outwards - the matter was already everywhere, it was space and the way we measure distance that was exploding according to the FLRW metric.

“Middle” of the Universe If we are in the “middle” of the observable universe, or even somewhere interior of the “blast”, then it makes sense that we see galaxies moving away from us in all directions. The uniformity of the CMB radiation could simply be the result of us being in the center of the universe’s observable region, not necessarily because the universe is homogenous or infinite.

Again, this makes a few wrong assumptions. This in particular not on you because you made the premises earlier and are now working from incorrect premises, but nonetheless those premises are wrong. There was no “blast” or “middle” of the Universe, and there never will be. It’s a very common misconception about the Big Bang that we, as a species, should really clear up with the laypeople before we move on to become a K1 civilization.
The probability of being anywhere near the center of the Universe, assuming it did in fact have one, is virtually nil. Any major anisotropies from being at all distant from the center would have been detected unless we were really at the center, and the probability that of the hundreds of billions or trillions of galaxies (or the infinite number, if you take space to be infinite, which according to your previous premises you do) is functionally zero (or exactly zero, even!). Even with a small finite estimate of the number of galaxies, picking one at random that happens to be near the center of the Universe for us humans to evolve on would never happen.

Alternatively, the Universe expanded from a singularity (i.e. the actual Big Bang happened), and then every galaxy would see roughly uniform CMBR and Universal expansion away from them. A much simpler model that much more accurately fits the data!
For the record: a physical theory (quantum mechanics, relativity, you know, the things that expert engineers used to design the device on which you read this and the GPS system that tracks it on the Earth’s surface) is never proven. I could arbitrarily say that all we’ve ever known about physics is wrong, there are no particles or stars or galaxies or anything, and there’s some mischievous Loki up there who just makes all our Universe look like it behaves and works the way we think it does with physics. That’s equally valid in terms of explaining the Universe: it still results in the same mechanics of the Universe. Of course that theory has issues (why does he not just make it impossible for us to see instead of doing so much work?), and it has the issue of unfalsifiability: there is no evidence that could possibly deny that theory.
In the same way we speak of cosmology. We can’t ever prove that cosmology as we know it today is correct, we can only note that all other competing theories either got falsifying evidence or were unfalsifiable to begin with. If we suddenly found a massive flaw in our model, we’d probably realize our error and pick out a different model! Of course, we’ve checked over our current model a great many times, and what issues we do have with it have not been conclusively proven impossible to fix.
It’s also unfortunate that the Big Bang is explained in the way it is in pop-sci, because the way it’s explained is wrong. But it’s the best model we have, so it’s important to interpret it correctly.

We make a huge assumption that redshift is related to velocity, and not simply a function of distance. We can observe methods of creating redshift due to velocity, but at the same time there's nothing disproving the concept that over extreme distances light waves don't elongate for other reasons. That's a significant flaw in arguments against what I've stated.

Redshift is related to velocity. You can observe this by watching a spacecraft as it flies away, or by watching planets as they move around, or by watching stars as they move. The fact that we can't disprove other potential causes is not support for there being other potential causes.. The burden of evidence is on you to provide evidence for some other mechanism of redshift, not on everyone else to conclusively disprove every other possible mechanism (which, in the exhaustive case, is impossible).

If photons have an infinitesimal amount of mass, then they would experience a slight delay over large distances (for example, due to gravitational effects or other mechanisms), which could lead to a decrease in their energy.
According to the energy-wavelength relationship, a reduction in energy would increase the wavelength, which would manifest as redshift.
Essentially, light would experience a kind of gradual slowing down or energy dissipation as it travels through space, which could be more noticeable over long distances, leading to redshift.

And yet we have never observed any masses for photons. Yes, that would be true if photons have nonzero mass, but all quantum-mechanical experiments (for example, the many that are done at CERN) all point to massless photons. That does not work as evidence for anything because that is an idea that has no evidence to support it. Why not accept the existing model that light is massless and that the Universe is expanding (which almost all our current evidence supports), unlike a brand-new theory (in  your case, which virtually no evidence supports)?

@mkinson Have you done the maths to see what formula would describe a redshift-distance relationship caused by a massive photon, in a Universe where galaxies move the way you suggest they do? Because I'll bet it doesn't work out as $z=\sqrt{\frac{c+H_0D}{c-H_0D}}$. It's not enough to just get the "making one variable bigger makes another bigger/smaller" detail right, especially considering what you're competing with.

Using a formula to calculate redshift using Hubbles constant would be irrelevant, considering I’m rejecting the concept of cosmic expanse as defined being the cause of redshift.

Redshift is caused by relative velocity, not expansion (although expansion does produce significant relative velocities). It’s essentially just the Doppler effect. You’re trying to reject a well-supported and very accurate model here… why, I can’t tell.
